# What is this round metal bar, 1" by 34"?

Tags: tools, identify-a-tool

The knob on the end kind of makes it look like a handle, but when held in my hands, smallish, it doesn't feel like it was made to be a handle.

Google image search didn't provide anything similar.

What is this round metal bar? It measures 1" dia and 34" long.  Only part is shown. The 1" diameter round stock continues to the right, unaltered. The other end is non-descript, it just ends.

It looks old. It's pitted. It is fairly straight, but not quite. It doesn't look like deviation from straight is intentional, more likely from misuse.  I picked it somewhere, years ago, probably in a freelist pile or at the dump when I took our trash there.

[image: 3/4" by 30"]

Comment: I wonder if it's held at the other end, in both hands, and this end is used to tamp something. Some ramrods even had a similar tip, but I can't find one quite right in an image search so I'm not confident to propose it as an answer

Comment: Could be.  On the other hand it's only 34" long and the knob has no signs of impacting anything hard. It's odd that the knob diameter is smaller than the 1" bar diameter.

Comment: The reduced diameter is a good reason to rule out a ramrod, *unless* it's missing a shoe on the end.  And thinking about it, you wouldn't want a cast iron ramrod in a cast iron barrel, because one spark and you'd have a cast iron ramrod in your head.  So if it was, which it probably isn't, it's incomplete.  Other tamping tools could still have had a head that's now lacking

Comment: Thanks for putting words to a vague feeling I had about the knob.  The knob could very well be for a pivoting head.

Comment: A tamper was my first impression.  For example packing down dirt around a fence post after you put it in the hole.

Comment: The knob is a smaller diameter than the rod, and the other end doesn't look to have been used in that regard at all. Maybe it is some type of axle or connecting rod.